# How to convert JSON object from third party api into local POJO

Tags: java, json, deserialization

Let's say i make a call to a thrid party API to get a object *Task* and I get the following JSON String in return:

```
 {
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "CODE",
        "description": "Dummy Task",
        "withConfirmation": false,
        "resource": {
          "id": "abcdef12-fe14-57c4-acb5-1234e7456d62",
          "group": "Doctor",
          "firstname": "Toto",
          "lastname": "Wallace",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "CODE",
        "description": "Dummyyy Taaask",
        "withConfirmation": false
      }
    ]
 }
```

In the returned json we have a **Task** which can be joined with a **Resource**.

In our system, a **Task** is as the following:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Task implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String code = "BASIC";
    private String description;
    private boolean withConfirmation = false;


    /**
     * CONSTRUCTOR
     */
    public Task() {
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public boolean isWithConfirmation() {
        return withConfirmation;
    }
    public void setWithConfirmation(boolean withConfirmation) {
        this.withConfirmation = withConfirmation;
    }

    public String toString() {...
    }
}
```

and a **Resource** looks like that:

```
public class Resource implements Serializable {
    ...

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private MedicalGroup group; // id + name + description
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);
    ...
    // getters and setters and toString etc.
    ...
}
```

So the major difference, aside from the field names is that a *Task* does not contain any *Resource* but the relation is rather in the opposite direction which means that a *Resource* can hold *n* *Task*.

What would be for this case the best way to **serialize** the returned json object from the third party and convert/map it to a pojo from my own system?
I'm currently reading Gson doc in order to try it but any suggestion is welcomed.
This code has to be easily reusable cause it's going to be needed inside multiple projects.

Comment: Do we have a joining field between resource and task or we need to introspect json response to figure out which task holds which resource?

Comment: we do have to introspect to find it out

Comment: An example to do this http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: @Naruto this is a simple example. my case is a bit more complicated and requires more treatment i think...

Comment: you have relation `resource have many tasks` , but json you are getting is `task have resource`, what  is problem creating bidirectional relation? it will make it ease for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not full working code, because i have no idea how you want to work with `Resource`. Should Json create new resource or try to find already existing one. How will you create `MedicalGroup` from json, because it is not enuogh data for that. I was going to ask this in comments, but there is not enough space. And here is demo how you can try to solve most of the problems except the `Resources to/from json` mapping.

Main idea is to add `@JsonAnyGetter public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties()` and `@JsonAnySetter public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Resource value)` in your `Task` POJO:

```
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {

        HashMap<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();

        // IMPORTANT
        // here we can try to find resource that has this task
        // and export its info to json like this:


        // CHANGE THIS
        Resource res = new Resource();
        res.firstname = "Toto";
        res.lastname = "Wallace";

        // IMPORTANT END

        map.put("resource", res);

        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Resource value) {
        // IMPORTANT
        // Here you have to create or find appropriate Resource in your code
        // and add current task to it
        System.out.println(name+" "+ value );
    }
```

**FULL Demo:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class Main3 {
private static String json = "{\n" +
        "    \"tasks\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"id\": 1,\n" +
        "        \"code\": \"CODE\",\n" +
        "        \"description\": \"Dummy Task\",\n" +
        "        \"withConfirmation\": false,\n" +
        "        \"resource\": {\n" +
        "          \"id\": \"abcdef12-fe14-57c4-acb5-1234e7456d62\",\n" +
        "          \"group\": \"Doctor\",\n" +
        "          \"firstname\": \"Toto\",\n" +
        "          \"lastname\": \"Wallace\"\n" +
        "      }},\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"id\": 2,\n" +
        "        \"code\": \"CODE\",\n" +
        "        \"description\": \"Dummyyy Taaask\",\n" +
        "        \"withConfirmation\": false\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        " }";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TasksList tl = mapper.readValue(json, TasksList.class);
    String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(tl);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static class TasksList {
    @JsonProperty(value = "tasks")
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Resource implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty(value = "firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @JsonProperty(value = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    // HAVE NO IDEA HOW YOU GONNA MAP THIS TO JSON
    // private MedicalGroup group; // id + name + description
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Resource{" +
                "firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                ", tasks=" + tasks +
                '}';
    }
}

@JsonAutoDetect
public static class Task implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String code = "BASIC";
    private String description;
    private boolean withConfirmation = false;

    /**
     * CONSTRUCTOR
     */
    public Task() {
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public boolean isWithConfirmation() {
        return withConfirmation;
    }
    public void setWithConfirmation(boolean withConfirmation) {
        this.withConfirmation = withConfirmation;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {

        HashMap<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();

        // IMPORTANT
        // here we can try to find resource that has this task
        // and export its info to json like this:
        // CHANGE THIS

        Resource res = new Resource();
        res.firstname = "Toto";
        res.lastname = "Wallace";

        // IMPORTANT END

        map.put("resource", res);

        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Resource value) {
        // IMPORTANT
        // Probably here you have to create or find appropriate Resource in your code
        // and add current task to it
        System.out.println(name+" "+ value );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", withConfirmation=" + withConfirmation +
                '}';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: just to let you know i'm going to test your solution as soon as possible and give you a feedback immediately after. Can be hard to focus on a single task sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Gson` library by google to convert `Json` to `Pojo Class`.

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,Response.class);
```